# What are the documented pros and cons of USB Type-C?

Tags: electrical-engineering

I have been investigating pros and cons USB Type-C. Obviously their are many advantages in innovation, so are the disadvantages. On such disadvantage is ["Those new USB-C cords can fry your laptop"](http://money.cnn.com/2016/02/05/technology/usb-c-cords/).

[image]

Advantages:

- Good bye to proprietary laptop power brick.
- Support both USB 2.0 and USB 3.0
- Higher data rate of 5 Gbps with USB 3.0

Disadvantages:

- Poor design could fry your expensive laptop.
- Shorter cable length. USB 3.0 cable length is 10 feet, where is USB 2.0 is 16 feet.

**Question**: What are other disadvantages that need to be considered when recommending USB Type-C?

---

**References:**

- [USB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB#USB_Type-C)
- [USB Type-C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_Type-C)
- [USB 3.0 – The Pros and Cons](https://giuseppemelle.wordpress.com/2010/06/06/usb-3-0-the-pros-and-cons/)
- [USB Type-C FAQ: Everything You Need to Know](http://www.laptopmag.com/articles/usb-type-c-faq)
- [SuperSpeed USB Developers Conference - USB.org](http://www.usb.org/developers/presentations/pres1108/SuperSpeed_USB_DevCon_Cable_and_Connnector_Ling.pdf)
- [Should USB 3.0 Be Used Instead of USB 2.0 in Your Next Computer?](http://www.chassis-plans.com/should-usb-3-0-be-used-instead-of-usb-2-0-in-your-next-computer/)

Comment: You didn't list the biggest plus: you don't need three tries to plug it in right. You also didn't mention the biggest minus: it is a new connector that requires new cables or adapters. Also, the pros and cons depend on the use. Are you using it for charging, power, or communication?

Comment: I'm casting the 5th vote-to-close on this question.  At its core, this question is essentially a poll.  Polls generally don't work well within the StackExchange Q&A format.  Likewise, asking about "What other disadvantages need to be considered..." is too open ended and doesn't present a specific problem to be resolved.  There are definitely some challenges to be addressed with the new(er) USB Type-C format, but I'm not able to find a way to revise this question to make it fit within the Q&A format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No -- any cable built **wrong** can fry your laptop.  The kerfluffle in the blogosphere is about off-brand cables which were incorrectly wired.  The whole point of USB-C is that the connector itself is orientation-agnostic and it (the *connector*) cannot be inserted in a way that sends power to the wrong lead.  Only a miswired cable can do that.